# How can I change HTML page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mule, anypoint-studio

I use jQuery in the index.html page. The goal is to send a json to another page:

```
postUploadUrl = "https://localhost:1580/ean/send/file"; 
$.post({
  url:postUploadUrl,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  data: resJson
});
```

otherpage.html is in another flow.

index.html and otherpage.html are in two different parse template

When I put a break point on the parse template of otherpage.html, I see that Mule goes in the good flow and stops on parse template of otherpage.html.
The problem is that he is not displaying the page autrepage.html. He still on the index.html page.

### Part of the flow where there is index.html

```
<choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="15c0c63d-4071-4d60-8817-5642ead5fbb6" >
            <when expression="#[vars.isLog != 'true']">
                <parse-template doc:name="index.html" doc:id="bba0a925-fcf3-46cd-9060-cdc4708ae418" location="ean\index.html"/>
          
</when>
            <otherwise >
            <flow-ref doc:name="Go_Login.hml" doc:id="0e2e49ac-92eb-4376-83ac-33b5c9ff3139" name="Login-Flow"/>
          </otherwise>
      </choice>
```

### Part of the flow where there is otherpage.html

```
<flow name="Insert-EanFlow" doc:id="16164463-1067-4fd9-9631-5836f4979e8e" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="fdd02707-02a8-4b3b-beee-79770b5f6eae" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/ean/send/file">

...
...
...
        <parse-template doc:name="Parse Template" doc:id="3dfe5b15-e3fa-4763-b5f4-d0ed41d05eb8" location="ean\otherpage.html" />
    </flow>
```

Please help.

Best regard.

Comment: `url:otherpage.html,` is missing quotes. It should be `url: "otherpage.html",`

Comment: Please add the XML of the flow so we can understand what it does.

Comment: Without understanding the application flows behavior it is very difficult to make suggestions. Note that Mule is not the one displaying pages nor executing jquery.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: I modified my post with more information.

I don't want to drown you in the code or exceed the number of characters, so I've put the parts I see important. Please let me know if you need more.


Best regards.

Comment: The title of this question is nonsensical. Please read [ask].